# Lenovo z585 bios update

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

So my Lenovo z585 laptop was having issues accessing the bios. I looked around online and it said I needed to update my bios. I downloaded the proper exe from the Lenovo website and ran it. It restarted my laptop and it now says preparing to configure windows, do not turn off your computer. It has been on this screen for a while and doesn't seem to be progressing. Any ideas to fix this? I really don't want to screw my laptop up so any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: How long has it been .....?

Comment: @Xavierjazz 25 to 30 mins